# cannot link to static mysqlclient library, though shared library works

Tags: mysql, c, linker, static-linking, dynamic-linking

I have a sample program to familiarize myself with mysqlclient APIs. However when I compile and link it to the mysqlclient library statically (`.a` file), the linker complains it cannot find the file, although it exists in my path. Linking to the shared library (`.dylib` file on my Mac) works.
Please help me get my head around this behaviour. Much appreciated!

Here's my driver program `client.c` that calls mysqlclient library.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <mysql.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
  MYSQL *mysql = NULL;

  if (mysql_library_init(argc, argv, NULL)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "could not initialize MySQL client library\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  mysql = mysql_init(mysql);

  if (!mysql) {
    puts("Init faild, out of memory?");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  if (!mysql_real_connect(mysql,       /* MYSQL structure to use */
              NULL,         /* server hostname or IP address */ 
              NULL,         /* mysql user */
              NULL,          /* password */
              NULL,               /* default database to use, NULL for none */
              0,           /* port number, 0 for default */
              NULL,        /* socket file or named pipe name */
              CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS /* connection flags */ )) {
    puts("Connect failed\n");
  } else {                
    const char *query = "SELECT VERSION()";
    if (mysql_real_query(mysql, query, strlen(query))) {
      printf("Query failed: %s\n", mysql_error(mysql));
    } else {
      puts("Query OK");
    }
  }

  mysql_close(mysql);

  mysql_library_end();

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Here's how I compile it

```
gcc -I /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.16/include/mysql client.c -L /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.16/lib/ -l mysqlclient.a
ld: library not found for -lmysqlclient.a
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Compiling without the `.a` succeeds, as it links to the shared library, not static one.

Lastly, here's my library files:

```
ls /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.16/lib/libmysqlclient*
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.16/lib/libmysqlclient.21.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.16/lib/libmysqlclient.a        /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.16/lib/libmysqlclient.dylib
```

Answer (score 1):

This argument:

```
 -l mysqlclient.a
```

causes the linker to look for a file named `libmysqlclient.a.a`. Instead, you want something like:

```
gcc -I /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.16/include/mysql client.c /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/8.0.16/lib/mysqlclient.a
```

Answer (score 1):

`-lmysqlclient` should work. The extension `.a` does not need.

When you want to use static link, `--static` should be used.

You may also need to link other libraries

```
gcc client.c -o client --static  -lmysqlclient  -lssl -lcrypto -ldl  -lpthread
```